# How to rewrite closing current tab function with "async/await" instead of ".then"?

Tags: protractor

For closing current tab in my test I use next function:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    browser.driver.close();
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

And it works good. But I must rewrite to "async/await" instead of ".then". I try next code:

```
async function goBackToPreviousTab () {
    let handles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        browser.driver.close();
        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
}
```

but in result receive next error:

*no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, understand that `.then` or `await` is a way of resolving Promises. So whatever returns a promise needs to be explicitly resolved. For example, [.close()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.close) returns a Promise too, and needs either of the syntax

This is why, back your question, your function should be

```
async function goBackToPreviousTab () {
    let handles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    await browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    await browser.driver.close();
    await browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
}
```

because each of your commands is a Promise